# c# finding appropriate list chain for known points

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, generic-list

```
   var route1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
   var route2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 };
   var route3 = new List<int> { 3, 7, 13 };
   var route4 = new List<int> { 8, 9, 10 };
```

Question is that; my origin point is 2 and my target point is 9. My aim is to find appropriate route chain. For this situtation my route will be [route1 - route3 - route2 - route4]. But I don't know how to solve this problem, I cannot find an algorithm. Answer can be pseudo code or c# implemantation.

My way is that; my start point (2) in route1, and my target point (9) in route4. Then I need to find middle route(s) which connects route1 and route4. I need algorithm or technique..

Comment: Brute force is an algorithm or technique you could use. Will you always have 4 routes of length 3?

Comment: Use google. *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work*

Comment: I can't figure out why you state route 1 - route 3 - route 2 - route 4 is the proper path from points 2 to 9.   Elaborate on that.

Comment: @user1646737 Which routes would you use? Route 1 is the only 1 with 'point 2' so you have to start there. From Route 1 you can only go to Route 3 (via 'point 3'). From Route 3 you can only go to Route 2 (via 7) or back to Route 1. From Route 2 you can go to Route 4 (via 8) (which contains 9) or back to Route 3.

Comment: @Bob2, I don't know.  It's ambiguous.  Must he traverse all 4 routes?  If not, I'd go route 1 (for point 2), stay at route 1 (for point 3), jump to route 2 because it is the next number higher than 3 and closer to 9, then, straight to route 4 because route 3 ended with point 8.

Comment: @user1646737 It seems your confusion lies in the fact that OP did not specify that you can only 'traverse' between numbers within a route and between two different routes with the same number. You can't go from route1 to route2 because they don't share a location.

Comment: numbers orders not important (you can see them like letters A,B,C), they are just represantations of some points (locations). @Bob2Chiv your way is right. Also route numbers can be unlimited..

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Well, there are a lot of ways to skin a cat.  One would be to take each list and convert its items to a single string of numbers padded by some number of "0"s.  He'd then have the ability to traverse 4 strings, and he could use  string.Contains().  If this is not clear, I can probably do the code easily enough.  The reason for left-padding with "000000000" is to make sure that Contains("2") doesn't catch 20, 21, 22, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will find the routes between any two points, should one exist. The route may not always be the shortest (for instance from 3 to 13 will give route1 to route3). It also uses recursion - which seems to be something you wanted (based on your tags). `vistedRoutes` contains the routes traversed.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var route1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var route2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 };
        var route3 = new List<int> { 3, 7, 13 };
        var route4 = new List<int> { 8, 9, 10 };

        List<List<int>> routeList = new List<List<int>>();
        routeList.Add(route1);
        routeList.Add(route2);
        routeList.Add(route3);
        routeList.Add(route4);

        int start = 3;
        int end = 9;

        var vistedRoutes = new List<List<int>>();

        foreach(var route in routeList.FindAll(r => r.Contains(start)))
        {
            vistedRoutes.Add(route);
            routeList.Remove(route);
            FindPath(vistedRoutes, routeList, start, end);

            if (vistedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }

    static void FindPath(List<List<int>> visitedRoutes, List<List<int>> remainingRoutes, int start, int end)
    {
        if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
        {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingRoutes.Count; i++ )
        {
            var route = remainingRoutes[i];

            foreach (var point in route)
            {
                if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(point))
                {
                    visitedRoutes.Add(route);
                    var newRemainingRoutes = new List<List<int>>(remainingRoutes);
                    newRemainingRoutes.Remove(route);
                    FindPath(visitedRoutes, newRemainingRoutes, start, end);
                    if (visitedRoutes.Last().Contains(end))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        visitedRoutes.Remove(route);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes you are right.. that's the solution. Despite my lack of descriptions you got it! :) thank you and also @user164673

Comment: sorry @Bob2Chiv i cannot find a solution to this situtaion, what if the routes will be {1,2,3,4} - {1,5,6,7} - {1,8,9,10} - {10,11,12,13}, for example origin point is 2 - target point 8, according to solution 1-2-3 routes will be chosen, but it should be only first and third routes.

Comment: As I said previously, this will not always give the shortest route - because it is a greedy approach. I'm sure it can be tweaked to do so; for instance, if you took this code and ran it several times against the input in various orders (r1,r2,r3,r4 -> r2,r1,r3,r4 -> r3,r1,r2,r4 etc) it would find the shortest route. That's because this code takes the 'first possible' route. You could also iterate through all of the routes in `FindPath`,  to see if you can skip to the end at a given point. BUT, this doesn't even always give the shortest path.

Comment: Getting the 'shortest' path is typically not a trivial problem; and if your input is limited, you'll probably want to try every combination. 

Or, perhaps you can adapt one of these algorithms to your problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
        var route1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var route2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 };
        var route3 = new List<int> { 3, 7, 13 };
        var route4 = new List<int> { 8, 9, 10 };

        List<List<int>> routeList = new List<List<int>>();
        routeList.Add(route1);
        routeList.Add(route2);
        routeList.Add(route3);
        routeList.Add(route4);

        int startPoint = 2;
        int endPoint = 9;


        List<List<int>> finalRouteOrder = new List<List<int>>();

        //  Find starting route.
        List<int> currentRoute = routeList.Find(a => a.Contains(startPoint));

        //  Don't need that route in the list anymore.
        routeList.Remove(currentRoute);

        //  Add it to our final list of routes.
        finalRouteOrder.Add(currentRoute);

        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            foreach (int x in currentRoute)
            {
                currentRoute = routeList.Find(a => a.Contains(x));
                if (currentRoute != null)
                {
                    finalRouteOrder.Add(currentRoute);  // add this route toi our final list of routes
                    routeList.Remove(currentRoute);  // remove that list since we are done with it.

                    if (currentRoute.Contains(endPoint))
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (done)
                    break;

            }
            if (done)
                break;
        }

        //  finalRouteOrder contains the routes in order.

        MessageBox.Show("Done.");
```

Comment: What if you go from point 6 to 9?